# Android Programming Good Practices. Listener in fragment/Activity or local parameter

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I would like to know about what's the best practice to handle `onClick` events in Android.

I usually use the following two ways:

1. The fragment or Activity implements the onClickListener

   ```
   public class MyActivity extends Activity  implements View.OnClickListener{

   private Button btn1;
   private Button btn2;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

       btn1= findViewById(R.id.btn1);
       btn2= findViewById(R.id.btn2);

       btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
       btn2.setOnClickListener(this);

   }


   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

       switch (v.getId()){
           case R.id.btn1:
               break;
           case R.id.btn2:
               break;
       }
   }
   ```

   }
2. I create a local onClickListener variable in the Activity or Fragment.

   ```
   public class MyActivity extends Activity {

   private Button btn1;
   private Button btn2;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

       btn1= findViewById(R.id.btn1);
       btn2= findViewById(R.id.btn2);

       btn1.setOnClickListener(listener);
       btn2.setOnClickListener(listener);

   }


   private View.OnClickListener listener= new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           switch (v.getId()){
               case R.id.btn1:
                   break;
               case R.id.btn2:
                   break;
           }
       }
   };
   ```

   }

What do you think is the best practice? From the point of view of performance and android programming good practices.

Answer (score 1):

There are religious wars over this.  Fortunately I'm wearing my nomex underwear today.

Your first example leads to your activity suffering from the antipattern known as interface bloat.  Both of your examples have the disadvantage of forcing you to look somewhere else to see what the listener you just attached actually does.  I very strongly prefer having all listeners be anonymous classes that are defined where the listener is added, and having each one do a single thing, eliminating those unwieldy switch blocks:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private Button btn1;
    private Button btn2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        btn1= findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // ...
            }
        });

        btn2= findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // ...
            }
        });
    }
}
```

There is not likely to be any significant performance difference with any of these styles, and maintainability should always trump micro-optimization.

Comment: Of course your implementation causes it to be very difficult to see what your onCreate is doing, especially if your onClick is non-trivial.  I don't need to see what happens when you click a button when I'm trying to read the code that's defining the creation of the activity-  the two have nothing to do with each other.  I agree on each doing a single thing though, no reason to use a single listener and switching later in the case of predefined buttons.  My personal preference is to define android:click in the xml, so the entire definition of the button is in xml.

Comment: I disagree that they have nothing to do with each other, but I do agree that with this style, `onCreate()` can quickly become cluttered and hard to read.  When that happens, I break out the initialization into other descriptively-named methods.